# rowwise tabulation in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Haveing a data.table as follows:

```
   station       w_1       w_2
1:    1757     ar_2d lm_h_step
2:    2171 lm_h_step lm_h_step
3:    2812 lm_h_step lm_h_step
4:    4501 lm_h_step lm_h_step
5:    4642     ar_2d lm_h_step
6:    5029     ar_2d lm_h_step
7:    5480 lm_h_step lm_h_step
8:    5779     ar_2d     ar_2d
9:    5792     ar_1d     ar_2d
```

I'd like to tabulate the frequency of the methods per station.
So the expected result would be

```
          1757  2171  2812 ...
lm_h_step    1     2     2
ar_2d        1     0     0 
ar_1d        0     0     0 ...
```

What i have tried so far:

```
apply(dat,1,table)
```

is producing the right result, but it is not propperly formated.

Any ideas?

Dput of the data:

```
structure(list(station = c(1757L, 2171L, 2812L, 4501L, 4642L, 
                           5029L, 5480L, 5779L, 5792L), w_1 = c("ar_2d", "lm_h_step", "lm_h_step", 
                                                                "lm_h_step", "ar_2d", "ar_2d", "lm_h_step", "ar_2d", "ar_2d"), 
               w_2 = c("lm_h_step", "lm_h_step", "lm_h_step", "lm_h_step", 
                       "lm_h_step", "lm_h_step", "lm_h_step", "ar_2d", "ar_2d")), .Names = c("station", 
                                                                                             "w_1", "w_2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                 -9L))
```

Comment: Btw, the data you've provided isn't matching the data structure you are showing.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't indicate anything that says "rowwise" to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ananda Mahto:
Rowwise because of the 1 in `apply(dat,1,table)` which produces the right result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `dcast/melt` combination

For `data.table` [**v >= 1.9.5**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) use this

```
dcast(melt(dat, "station"), value ~ station, length)
#        value 1757 2171 2812 4501 4642 5029 5480 5779 5792
# 1:     ar_1d    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
# 2:     ar_2d    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    2    1
# 3: lm_h_step    1    2    2    2    1    1    2    0    0
```

---

For `data.table` **v < 1.9.5** you will also need to load `reshape2` and explicitly use `dcast.data.table` (because `reshape2::dcast` isn't generic and 
doesn't have a `dcast.data.table` method).

`reshape2::melt`, on the other hand, is generic (see `methods(melt)`) and has a `melt.data.table` method so you won't need to tell it anything. It will know which method you want to use depending on the `class` of `dat`

```
require(reshape2)
dcast.data.table(melt(dat, "station"), value ~ station, length)
#        value 1757 2171 2812 4501 4642 5029 5480 5779 5792
# 1:     ar_1d    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
# 2:     ar_2d    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    2    1
# 3: lm_h_step    1    2    2    2    1    1    2    0    0
```

---

If you are not picky with strictly using `data.table` methods, you can also use `reshape2::recast` (see @shadows comment) which is a wrapper for the solution above but using `reshape2::dcast` instead of `dcast.data.table` and thus will return a `data.frame` object instead of a `data.table`

```
recast(dat, value ~ station, id.var = "station", length)
#       value 1757 2171 2812 4501 4642 5029 5480 5779 5792
# 1     ar_1d    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
# 2     ar_2d    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    2    1
# 3 lm_h_step    1    2    2    2    1    1    2    0    0
```

Comment: Or in one step using `recast`: `recast(dat, value ~ station, id.var = "station", fun.aggregate = length)`

Comment: @shadow I'm only using `data.table` package here. It could be done with `reshape2` I guess, but it will be probably less efficient.

Comment: That's true in the development version of `data.table`. The release version doe not actually have a function `dcast` yet, but requires the use of `dcast.data.table`. So for me, your code uses `reshape2::dcast` instead of `dcast.data.table`.

Comment: @shadow, fair enough. I haven't used v 1.9.4 for very long time now and forgot about this behavior. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thank you. I didn't know that dcast used to be not generic.